# How do i create object approval from aws management console or aws cli for S3 object

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, amazon-cloudfront

I am using Django boto3 module to upload images and videos to AWS S3 and also using cloudfront CDN.

User create their account and upload images and videos to AWS S3 , but i want to put a check and implement admin approval for video and images .

Currently, the images and videos uploaded in AWS s3 via Django app is public by default.

Can it be possible via AWS management console or AWS cli to implement admin approval for images and videos?
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

use some specific prefix (like "unapproved") when user uploads files .

create one application(Admin Panel) on web/mobile, there you can show/list of image files prefixed with "unapproved".

now check and approve ( one button) .. after approve, copy original file and rename it with "approved" prefix or simply without prefix to s3 and delete old one..